# Sequelize - How to automatically retrieve child records from a query to the parent table?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize 3.24.3 to connect to a MySQL database.

In the database I have a one-to-many relationship between two tables - Paper & PaperVersion. 1 Paper can have multiple versions.
My requirement is to write a single query to retrieve a paper from the Paper table, the returned resultset should also contain the versions associated with the paper.

This is how my models look like:

```
    var Paper = sequelize.define("paper", {
        Author: DataTypes.STRING,
        Status: DataTypes.ENUM('Pending Submission','Submitted)
    });

    var PaperVersion = sequelize.define("paperVersion", {
            ID: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true
            },
            Title: DataTypes.STRING,
            Description: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        {
            classMethods:
            {
                associate: function(models){
                    PaperVersion.belongsTo(models.paper);
                }
            }
        });
```

This is how I execute the select statements:

```
        PaperModel.findAll({
        })
        .then(function(papers){
            // do some processing
        });

        PaperVersion.find({
            where:{
              paperId:paper.id,
             }
         }).then(function(version){
            // do some processing
           });
```

When I to execute a find or findAll on either the Paper or PaperVersion model I get records from only the Paper or PaperVersion table. 
I read somewhere that it is possible to include records from the associated tables in the resultset. Can someone please let me know how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
PaperModel
  .findAll({
    include: [{ model: PaperVersion}]
   })
  .then(function(papers) {
    // do some processing
  });
```

Comment: I receive the following error: Unhandled rejection Error: PaperVersion is not associated to paper!

Comment: ignore my previous comment. my model and database were not in sync. I got it working after a force sync. Thanks!